"WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:80/' failed" with a self-signed SSL
I am trying to create my own websocket with Workerman library and connect my frontend part with the server. I am using Apache2 to run it.
So, let's see, how it looks like:
$worker = new Worker('websocket://127.0.0.1:80');

$worker->onMessage = function($connection, $data) use($worker) {
    foreach($worker->connections as $clientConnection) {
        $clientConnection->send('Hello World');
    }
};

Worker::runAll();

let socket = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:80');

Nothing's really special, just the way it should be done. At least as I see it.
I got no problem with opening the page with the address:
https://localhost/websocket/test.html

However, I get the error on my browser JS console:
WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:80/' failed

Well, ofc I tried many different ways to fix it that people recommended under similar topics.
I tried to open the page with the '127.0.0.1' in address instead of 'localhost'. The same thing. I tried to change 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' in address for connection in JS code - still nothing changes.
My self-signed SSL certificate works fine though the browser tells me the connection is not secure. At least I can ignore it and open the page. Still, the page can't get connection to the websocket.
My browser is Google Chrome. I also tried the things in Firefox, still getting what I get.
UPD: I changed port to 443. For some reason when I use
let socket = new WebSocket('wss://127.0.0.1:443');

I get the following error in browser console:
WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1/' failed

Like it doesn't see the port number anymore, because I'm not sure if it even should.
here you can see that the files with websocket and the main page are in the same directory, which is /var/www/html/websocket/

You really use TLS (wss, https) on port 80 which is the default port for non-TLS (ws, http)?

Not sure if this is really a duplicate to the question I've linked to (and you need to add an explicit exception for the site) or if you are simply using the wrong port (non-TLS port for TLS). Providing "does not work" as the only information is not helpful. Look at the browser console for more detailed errors.

If the browser tells you, your connection is not secure. Then you don't use a self signed certificate. Therefor use ws:// (not secure) - not wss:// (secure).

@SteffenUllrich The thing is that browser console gives me only what I have shown you. I'll try to check what the thing is is with the port 80 and update the question or ask additional questions, thank you

@Christopher I tried using only ws in a first place. But because it didn't work I thought the problem was with me not having ssl certificate. Still I get the same error anyway, secure or not

@SteffenUllrich also I edited the question with the mention I get the error in Google Chrome, not only Firefox, while op from that question get the problem only in Firefox. And 'does not work' literally means I get the same error I've already mentioned

@SandroSandro: I've reopened the question. Please provide a minimal example so that one can reproduce your error, like the main page which embeds the Javascript to access the Websocket, which URL you use for the main page, which URL the websocket is, how the server is configured.

@SandroSandro the site you use to establish a connection to the websocket, uses a secure connection? Consider taking a look at the Workermen Docs: Transport Encryption - SSL/TLS or setup a proxy/tunnel on your webserver. (Apache2, nginx) - Browsers won't let you connect from https:// to ws:// (mixed content security).

@Christopher of course I knew this before and tried ws with http in a first place. Got the same error, though.

@SteffenUllrich Unfortunately switching to 443 port didn't work, at least I see a similar error. I've updated the question

Well, the problem was really in a port number, I did not understand which one I should've use, and the one should've not been in use, 3000, for example.
Also, Workerman expects you to configure your way of connection with the socket if you want to use ssl, so I needed to add this to my server.php file:
$context = array(
'ssl' => array(
    'local_cert'  => './cert/myCA.pem',
    'local_pk'    => './cert/myCA.key',
    'verify_peer' => false,
)
);
 $worker = new Worker('websocket://127.0.0.1:3000', $context);
 $worker->transport = 'ssl';

